# Using select_month in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working in Ruby on Rails and I cant figure out how to use select_month in a form_for.  What I am trying is:

```
<%= form_for(@farm) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :harvest_start %><br />
<%= select_month(Date.today, :field_name => 'harvest_start') %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

which is outputting

```
["harvest_start", nil]
```

Comment: the following code is what i got to work.

Comment: <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :harvest_start %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :harvest_start, Farm::MONTHS,
     :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
  </div>

Comment: @farm.harvest_start = params[:harvest_start]

Comment: i also got select_month to work but i needed the :include_blank and i didn't want to spend the time figuring out what to do with the nil in an array.

Comment: Apologies for the late comment.Did you have your solution worked.?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use select month consistently with the rest of your form builder, use `date_select` without the day or month:

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Just use `f.date_select :harvest_start, {order: [:month]}` i.e. add `order: [:month]` or `discard_year: true, discard_day: true` to the `options` hash, as specified in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)

The benefit of this you can pass in all the remaining options as you would in the options hash. Something like:

```
<%= f.date_select :birth_date, {prompt: true, order: [:month]}, class:  'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 2):

> (this was answered in comments by T. Weston Kendall so just making it a proper answer)

the following code is what i got to work.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :harvest_start %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :harvest_start, Farm::MONTHS, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
</div>
```

**farms_controller.rb**

```
@farm.harvest_start = params[:harvest_start]
```

i also got select_month to work but i needed the `:include_blank` and i didn't want to spend the time figuring out what to do with the nil in an array.